# The fur I'm trying to make isn't looking like real fur. It's coarse and I don't know how to fix it

Tags: node-editor

I am trying to make fur, but for some reason, I can't seem to get it to be softer it is coarse and doesn't look soft as all. I made a little ball of fur as an example of this: [image]

Sorry if the title doesn't convey my message clearly, I wasn't sure how else to put it. If anyone has any way of fixing this I would love to know, thanks. 
[image]

Comment: Can  you show your work as  a Blender screen capture?

Comment: Pic added. I put the blend file there though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have clumping at 100%, which will make it look coarse.

In Particle Properties->Children->Clumping I changed *Clump* to 0 and in Particle Properties->Children->Roughness I changed *Random* to 0.5.  Whilst this may not be exactly what you are after, it looks a lot more 'softer'

[image]

Comment: That looks a lot better, I'll have to try it out, thank you.